# "She refuses to pay the fine, and she took the matter to court." Is the sentence correct with two different tenses?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

Is this sentence from an English Learning magazine grammatically correct  with two different tenses in one sentence?

> She **refuses** to pay the fine, and she **took** the matter to court.

My opinion is she still refuses to pay the fine, so she took the matter to the court in the past. I don't see any contradiction.  We are confused with the sentence consisting of two opposing verb tenses and had a debate about it on another site. I feel it does make sense somehow. Because she refuses to pay the fine, still as well, she took this matter to the court.

Answer (score -1):

Used correctly, you can use 2 different tenses in one sentence.

However, this:

> She **refuses** to pay the fine, and she **took** the matter to court.

is not correct - it does not even respect the chronology of events.

The following may be used:

> She **refused** to pay the fine, and (therefore) she **takes** the matter to court (today).

It means that she made a decision in the past (refused) and there is a consequence in the present (takes to court).

Comment: *She refuses to pay the fine, and because she feels so strongly about it, she took the matter to court where it is still pending.*